# 301 redirect ?cat=

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Google Webmaster Tools are constantly showing this version of my domain name:

mysite.co.uk/?cat=

I have disallowed every URL with ? in it and the above shows under the Crawl errors: URL restricted by robots.txt

I simply don't know why is that happening when I've got the following in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://misite.co.uk/? [R=301,L]
```

I thing the above is supposed to 301 redirect: 
mysite.co.uk/?cat= 
to: 
mysite.co.uk/

and also if I click the first URL it actually goes to the second one in the browser.

I've got a couple more similar issues with ? URLs and I'll be really happy if somebody tells me how to properly 301 redirect them in order to show Google that these have been permanently removed and stop them from being crawled.

Comment: For reference, you might find better help on http://serverfault.com or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com .  Either would be more familiar with configuring Apache.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate HTTP response status code to tell a resource has been permanently removed would be [410 Gone](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.11):

> The requested resource is no longer available at the server and no forwarding address is known. This condition is expected to be considered permanent. Clients with link editing capabilities SHOULD delete references to the Request-URI after user approval. […]

Sending this response status code will make search engines remove the requested URI from the index. But they might be crawled after all if there still are links with that URI.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer and I'll apply the 410. About the URL - this is a WordPress site and ?cat has got something to do with the categories. My permalink structure for the categories is: mysite.co.uk/news/some-post-here. The /news/ is the category. What's more there's no links what so ever to point to ?cat URL! I've been using 301 http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633 for 2-3 years now to redirect old pages etc without any problems - soon after the redirect the URLs drop from the index which is my idea. This doesn't happen to the URL above though?!

Comment: @Zmey: Yes, [responding with a 410 will remove the URL from the index](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=64033). But a 410 is not a redirection, it’s a dead end.

Comment: @Zmey: You are confused by what? A 410 just means that the “requested *resource* is no longer available at the server and no forwarding address is known.” So it’s a dead end. In opposite to that, a 301 means that only the *URI* for the requested resource should no longer be used as “requested resource has been assigned a *new permanent URI* and any future references to this resource SHOULD use one of the returned URIs.” So it’s a redirection.

Comment: Confused by which is better to use from G's point of view. I still can not find where this mysite.co.uk/?cat= comes from and how Google finds this URL if it's been 301 redirected for 3 years now! I'll have to apply the 410 as a final resort I guess. Thanks!

Comment: @Zmey: Google doesn’t care. But you should care what you want to express. If the resource is gone, use 410; if only the URI has changed, use 301.